# If a woman has a daughter with one man and has a son with the other man, does that mean that the son and the father of the daughter are related?

Tags: legal-terms, children

A woman named Maria has an illegitimate daughter with a man named Gabe. After she leaves the child in his care, Maria then marries a man named Rob. She has a child with Rob. Are Gabe and Rob's son related?

Comment: For what purpose and where? The law does not define terms in the same way for all purposes. The incest statute might use one definition, an inheritance statute another, a statute regarding standing to be a guardian or executor or have custody rigthts their own rules, relatives for purposes of being insiders to fraudulent transfers or insider trading another, and insiders for purposes of corporate control for tax purposes yet another. Also, different legal systems define family relationships differently. In English, one often calls them stepfather and stepson, even though it isn't technical so.

Comment: Of course assuming that Rob and Gabe are not brothers, for example.

Comment: What's your own view, please? How does anyone being illegitimate come into blood relationships… or is this not about blood relationships but for instance, legal inheritance?

Comment: Broadly, the son and the father of the daughter are related by marriage but their relationship is too distant to have any legal meaning.

Answer (score 6):

Unless Rob and Gabe are related, Rob and the son are not biologically related.

You can become legally related without being biologically related. For example, by adoption, by filling out a birth certificate (possibly incorrectly or lying), in some countries through a legal assumption that a woman's husband is the father of her children, including for some time after a divorce, unless father or mother actively prevent this from happening.

So if she divorces Gabe in June (because she has an affair with Rob and is highly pregnant with Rob's child), marries Rob in July, and her son is born in August, then in some countries Gabe *might* be legally Rob's father, and that matches your description. More likely if the son is born in July and she marries in August. Gabe will likely be able to go to court and change this, all depending on the jurisdiction.

Answer (score 3):

[british-columbia](/questions/tagged/british-columbia)

For all purposes of British Columbia law, "a person is the child of the person's parents" ([*Family Law Act*, s. 23(1)(a)](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/00_11025_00_multi#section23)).

"On the birth of a child not born as a result of assisted reproduction, the child's parents are the birth mother and the child's biological father" ([s. 26(1)](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/00_11025_00_multi#section26)). This includes many presumptions about who the biological father is.

There is no necessary legal relationship between Gabe and Rob's son. However, one could arise if:

- Gabe is the donor, by means other than sexual intercourse, of reproductive material from which the son that Maria has while in a marriage-like relationship with Rob is conceived, and Gabe, Maria, and Rob enter into an agreement that the three of them will all be parents of the son (under [s. 30(1)(b)(ii)](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/00_11025_00_multi#section30));
- Gabe becomes a guardian of Rob's son (under [s. 51](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/00_11025_00_multi#section51)) (note, this is not a *parentage* relationship);
- the parties enter into an agreement or obtain a court order that Gabe have contact with Rob's son ([ss. 58-59](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/00_11025_00_multi#section58)) (this is also not a *parentage* relationship);
- Gabe adopts Rob's son (under the *Adoption Act*) (this *is* a parentage relationship); or
- Gabe assumes stepparent duties in relation to Rob's son (under [s. 147(4)](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/00_11025_00_multi#section147)) (this is not a *parentage* relationship, but may bring child-support obligations).

It would take intentional effort to create a legal relationship between Gabe and Rob's son, not all of which would be parentage relationships. In British Columbia, it is the relationship of parentage that has the most significant legal effects.

This should also highlight [ohwilleke's point](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/96437/if-a-woman-has-a-daughter-with-one-man-and-has-a-son-with-the-other-man-does-th#comment223469_96437) that "related"-ness can have many meanings depending on the context and the province or state. Legal relationships also do not go hand-in-hand with colloquial understandings of whether two people are related.